# Intrinsic ratio for an inline SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, intrinsic-ratio

I'm building an inline SVG with JS. The proportions (aka ratio) of the SVG is dynamic: at any moment it can be changed from JS.

I would like to make the SVG responsive. This is how i would do it with an `<img>`:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But this won't work for `<svg>`. Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/vobaq/1/edit?html,css,output

**The goal is to scale the inline SVG element to fit container horizontally without distorting it's proportions. CSS should not know current SVG proportions.**

Comment: Thx Robert, i figured it out, see below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `viewbox` attribute instead of `width` and `height`. Then you don't even need CSS `width: 100%; height: auto;`!

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vobaq/4/edit?html,css,output